# strftime formatting - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, time, strftime

I've got a string 3:01 AM - 18 Dec 2017

I've written the following pattern `strftime('%-I:%M %p - %-d %b %Y')` and I can't seem to get it to work, following [this](https://strftime.org)

My notes:

- `%-I` hour 12-hour clock as a decimal (no zero padding)
- `:` separation between hour and minute
- `%M` minute as a zero padded decimal
- `%p` AM/PM
- `-` space-dash-space pattern betwen time and date
- `%-d` date of the month as a decimal (no zero padding)
- `%b` Month abbreviated
- `%Y` Year with century as decimal

`df['tweet_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tweet_date'], errors='coerce').apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')`

On another dataframe with a similar column this works:

```
df2['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['created_at'], errors='coerce').apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
df2['created_at'] = df2['created_at'].astype('datetime64[s]')`
```

where values before formatting look like this for example `2017-10-03T15:48:10.000Z`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't seem to get it to work"? What code have you written and how exactly does it not work? How do you expect it to work? What happens instead?

Comment: editing for more info

Comment: Do you want to *parse* a string into a datetime? Then use `strptime`. `strftime` *formats* a datetime into a string.

Comment: If you have a string, don't call `strftime()` on it. That is for turning times into strings. If you want to interpret your string as a time you need `strptime()`.

Comment: everything is a string in this dataframe, strftime works on another pattern on strings. looks like something's off with the pattern.

Not on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is fine but some os's can't use the negative formatting for zero-padded units. `datetime` should be able to parse both padded and non-padded instances of those just fine:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

z_time = '06:48 PM - 03 Jun 2021'
nz_time = '6:48 PM - 3 Jun 2021'

dt.strptime(z_time, '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')
[out:] datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 3, 18, 48)

dt.strptime(nz_time, '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')
[out:] datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 3, 18, 48)
```

And since you're getting strings from `datetime`s, you should look whether your os supports certain formatting rules. Here's one [for windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160#generic-text-routine-mappings).

Comment: This is about `strptime()`. Python calls the underlying C platform's implementation of `strftime()` but  "`strptime()` is independent of any platform and thus does not necessarily support all directives available that are not documented as supported" (*Standard Library*, 16.3, `time`). So the MSC documentation of its C library for Windows is a less reliable guide than the Python Standard Library documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To turn your string into a time, do this:

```
>>> import time
>>> s  = "3:01 AM - 18 Dec 2017"
>>> time.strptime(s,'%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=3, tm_min=1, 
tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=352, tm_isdst=-1)
```

No hyphens after `%`. The are not mentioned in the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: hyphens are for `strftime`

Comment: @van They are still not in the official documentation. They may work on some platforms. Not on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
str="3:01 AM - 18 Dec 2017"
date=datetime.strptime(str,"%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to figure out how to use `strftime` in a lambda function or better, using the `.dt` accessor after the column in my dataframe had been converted to a datetime

I couldn't figure this out so I went for the next fastest method

```
from datetime import datetime
formatted_dates = []
for item in df.tweet_date:
    formatted_dates.append(datetime.strptime(item,"%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y"))
df.tweet_date = formatted_dates
```